# Create string partitioned table from select in BigQuery

Tags: sql, select, google-bigquery

I have quite complex query which I would like to use to create a table.

To create a regular table I can just run:

```
CREATE TABLE schemaName.tableName AS
WITH
my_query AS (SELECT ...)
SELECT col1, ... colN FROM my_query
```

Is there a way how to create this table partitioned by column `col1` if `col1` is a non-date string?

Comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35905817 you may monitor this feature request to get notified when it is done.

Comment: Thanks, I wonder how much longer will it take. This request is over 3 years old now. I was actually surprised that BQ does not support partitioning with other than date fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of partitioniong, consider clustering:

```
CREATE TABLE schemaName.tableName
PARTITION BY fake_date
CLUSTER BY col1

AS
WITH
my_query AS (SELECT ...)
SELECT col1, ... colN, DATE('2000-01-01') fake_date 
FROM my_query
```

Benefits:

- https://medium.com/google-cloud/bigquery-optimized-cluster-your-tables-65e2f684594b

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Interesting is that when I create 2 tables: `table_1` without any clustering and partitioning and `table_2` with what you suggested, then when I write a query for these tables using `WHERE` with `col1`, I see that query on top of `table_2` will process more GB (5.8GB vs 4.9GB for `table_1`). I expected that it will be actually lower for the clustered table.

Comment: So I opened another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58625430/how-to-check-price-of-executed-queries-in-bigquery) to see how can I see price of executed query and based on that I actually see that querying clustered table is much cheaper. Pity that the information about how much GB will be processed before running a query is not probably taking clustering into consideration.