# How to check price of executed queries in BigQuery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, cloud

Is there a way to check price for queries I executed on BigQuery?

I know I can see the estimate before running a query (e.g. `This query will process 5.2 GB when run.`), with information like 1TB ~ $5 but I would actually like to see how much I pay for exact queries I have already run (price per query executed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check billing bytes (vs. processed bytes) in BigQuery UI - both Classic and New going to respectively "Details" and "Job Information"

[image]

[image]